# Obtaining spaces in hyperlink

Tags: spacing, hyperref

I want a hyperlink in a paper that I am writing. I'm using the `hyperref` package and then `\href{<website>}{\nolinkurl{<Thing_with_spaces>}}`. How do I go about getting spaces displayed for `<Thing_with_spaces>`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{\nolinkurl{I Like TEX Stackexchange}}

\end{document}
```

What will display is `ILikeTEXStackexchange` with a little blue box around it. I would like spaces to occur between the words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\nolinkurl` is used for displaying a URL, but without activating a link. In this case it's overkill (and it mangles spaces); just use `\texttt` if you want typewriter type:

```
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{\texttt{I Like TeX Stackexchange}}
```