# Proper linebreaks in teletype font

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, typewriter

In my bibliography, I want to include report numbers of technical reports in teletype font. These report numbers typically consist of several blocks of letters and numbers connected by hyphens, like `INSTITUTE-YEAR-MM-NUMBER`. It is fine for the report numbers to have a line break after any of the hyphens.

So far, I have been using `\nolinkurl` without much thought, and it provides good results. Now, I need to include report numbers that have one block separated from the rest by a space. This space is suppressed by `\nolinkurl`. [In this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125436/103046) to the same issue, the accepted answer is to use `\texttt` instead. However, with `\texttt`, the automatic line breaks don't work.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand{\thereport}{REPORT-19-12-001 SPECIAL}
\begin{document}
This is a long line and at the end of the line there should be \texttt{\thereport} referenced.

This is a long line and at the end of the line there should be \nolinkurl{\thereport} referenced.
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I have report numbers with hyphens and spaces in teletype font with automatic line breaks?

Comment: Add `obeyspaces` to `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens, obeyspaces}{url}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\path`, with a modification to expand the contents.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens,obeyspaces}{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\epath}[1]{\expandafter\path\expandafter{#1}}

\newcommand{\thereport}{REPORT-19-12-001 SPECIAL}

\begin{document}

This is a long line and at the end of the line there should be
\epath{\thereport} referenced.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your output is missing the space between 001 and SPECIAL too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the hyphenat package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand{\thereport}{REPORT-19-12-001 SPECIAL}
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
\begin{document}
This is a long line and at the end of the line there should be \texttt{\thereport} referenced.

This is a long line and at the end of the line there should be \nolinkurl{\thereport} referenced.


\end{document}
```

Or you could reset the hyphenchar `\ttfamily \hyphenchar\font=45` (in the preamble).